# GN deleting instances based on selection or propagating iinstance scale to new points

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Is there a way currently in geometry nodes (b3.0) to delete instances in the graph or to propagate the instance scale to new points so I can remove the instances as a points and re -instance them with the correct scaling.

Comment: Are you sure you need to delete and re-instance them? What prevents you from defining the desired scale when they're first instanced? Or you can always use the Scale Instance node to scale them. Might need to see some details of what you're trying and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @ajwood I'm using a raycast to determine the scale of the instances, then converting the them to points to fetch the centroid and using the input mesh as a mask for selecting the points that are placed in undesired locations. deleting works by using the input mesh as a boolean (instancing small planes for subtractive bool) But couldn't get the raycast scale to propagate correctly to the points with different indices and locations. Its probably possible to do some pre transforming on the raycast points to get it to propagate based on coord. But scaling to 0 works for my application too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by scaling the instances to 0 instead of deleting them. This functionality will probably get added in the future. I did get a boolean on points working by instancing very small planes & using instance to points after that. Propagating the correct scaling attribute would probably  entail retaining the target point coordinates throughout the operations.[image: Scaling to 0 solution]